# Getting elements from an array where next element greater than previous by 1

Tags: java

I have an array:

```
int[] arr = {-4, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 18};
```

The array is ordered in ascending order.
The main idea is to get elements and group them, where next element is greater than a previous by 1. The minimum length of such elements should be equal 3.

In output, I have to get a string:

```
"-4, (-2-1), (3-6), 9, 10, (12-14), 18"
```

The first interval is:
-2, -1, 0, 1 - it should looks like range i.e -2-1

The next interval is:
3, 4, 5, 6 - it should looks like range i.e 3-6

9, 10 - the length is less than 3

So the last interval is:

12, 13, 14  it should looks like range i.e 12-14

Comment: The code you mentioned should work correctly

Comment: It also does not output what is shown as the `output:`

Comment: Please show in detail what output you are expecting and what output you are currently getting.

Answer (score 0):

this answer was pre-edit.

You are printing input[i] but you are expecting the values in  input[i] - 1

when you run this in the debugger you can see it finds -1 (which has -2 before it, and equals -2 + 1). You then print the -1 you found.

If you want the output to contain the -2 , you should print input[i - 1]

post-edit:

you have grouped elements by braces which means you are looking for a sequence. This will require you to keep the start number somewhere. the code you originally posted (simple loop that checks left) will need a bit more work.

In rough terms:

```
if (continuing a range) 
    if(this number is still in range / +1) continue
    else: stop the range and print it (start point plus current -1). if current -1 is the start point, don't use braces and range indicator. if it is different use braces and - between start and end)
else 
    start a range. (keep track of the number you are on and continue.
```

that's what you need in pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

#### Algorithm

You could loop through the array.

1. If found consecutive number, add it to a group (e.g. `List`).
2. If group satisfies minimum length (e.g. `3`) then add it to output formatted as range (and clear the group).
3. If no consecutive number, just add it to output.

#### Code

```java
public static String formatAsRange(List<Integer> list) {
    return String.format("(%d-%d)", list.get(0), list.get(list.size()-1));
}

public static String consecutiveElements(int[] array, int minGroupLength) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Integer> group = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || array[i] == array[i-1] + 1) {
            group.add(array[i]);
        } else  {
            if (group.size() >= minGroupLength) {
                sb.append(formatAsRange(group)).append(',');                
            } else {
                var csv = group.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                sb.append(csv).append(',');
            }
            group.clear();
            sb.append(array[i]).append(',');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

For your input it prints:
`-4,-2,(-1-1),3,(4-6),9,10,12,13,14,18,`

See the [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/uiq1Dc).

#### To do

So there is still something to fix. For example

- expected range `12-14` is missing
- expected range `-2-1` is not complete with `-2, (-1-1)`
- expected range `3-6` is not complete with `3, (4-6)`
- the last comma can be removed
- can add a space following each comma

Comment: array[i] == array[i-1] + 1 This statement doesn't include the first digit in sequence -2. This is it - my problem. I don't know, how to include entire sequence. First or last digit is been losing